# Docker: How to make Supervisor exit when there's an error

Tags: python, django, docker, supervisord

I have a Docker container running Supervisor with 2 processes:

- Celery
- Django

I want Supervisor to exit when one of these processes returns an error.

This is my configuration:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
loglevel=debug
logfile=/app/supervisord.log
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid
childlogdir=/app

[program:django]
command=python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/dev/fd/1
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0


[program:celery]
command=celery -A myapp worker --beat --scheduler django --loglevel=debug
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/dev/fd/1
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0

[eventlistener:processes]
command=bash -c "printf 'SUPERVISORD READY' && while read line; do kill -SIGQUIT $PPID; done < /dev/stdin"
events=PROCESS_STATE_STOPPED,PROCESS_STATE_EXITED,PROCESS_STATE_FATAL
```

When I have a fatal error that should normally make Docker exit, Supervisor tries to launch Django again and again.. while the goal is to exit.

What's missing here?
I tried different other configurations but it's not working.

Comment: Also you do not want to run runserver in production https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#runserver rather do proper deployment https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/

Comment: Yeah sure. I'm just still trying things in dev.

Comment: Do these need to run in a single container?  You could run them in separate containers, without supervisord, with alternate commands but based on the same image, and then use Docker's ordinary process supervision.

Comment: You seem to have implemented the suggestion posted at https://gist.github.com/tomazzaman/63265dfab3a9a61781993212fa1057cb for stopping supervisor when any process stops, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

As [documented](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html) [`autorestart`]

Default: unexpected

> If unexpected, the process will be restarted when the program exits
> with an exit code that is not one of the exit codes associated with
> this process’ configuration (see exitcodes)

Comment: Do you mean I should set "autorestart=false"? Because even with this, the process does not restart (that's okay) but Docker does not exit (not okay). My goal is to exit Docker in case of error.

Comment: supervisord has nothing to do with running docker container, docker container exits when main process finishes usually written in entrypoint.sh and your question does not provide with docker config, this has nothing to do with supervisor. Having both runserver and celery in same container also makes no sense from control perspective, neither usage of supervisord and docker together